# Warning CA1801 on extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, code-analysis

I want to implement an extension method over HtmlHelper on ASP.Net MVC
Like this:

```
  public static MvcHtmlString ExtensionMethod(this HtmlHelper html)
  {
     //some code not using html parameter
  }

  //For Razor Call like:
  @Html.ExtensionMethod();
```

I dont need in this case to use the html parameter. What is the more elegant way to supress CA1801 warning?

Thanks!

Comment: If it were me, I'd use `#pragma warning disable CA1801` and `#pragma warning restore CA1801` around the relevant code block.